# Python : Get the values of list of keys from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of

```
List=[{'ManufStr': '',
       'ProdStr': 'QWER1025',
       'SerialNum': 'ABCDEF0123456789',
       'VendorID': '0xa34',
       'ProdID': '0x4007'},
      {'ManufStr': '',
       'ProdStr': 'ASDF452x',
       'SerialNum': 'ABCDEF0123456789',
       'VendorID': '0xa34',
       'ProdID': '0x4007'}]
```

How can i get the values of VendorID, ProdID and ProdStr and then join them all together to make one string string?
such as  `VID0xa34&PID0x4007 ASDF452x`

Comment: It is very unclear how your resulting string is generated. You take `VendorID` and `ProdID` from the first dictionary in the list and then add the `ProdStr` of the second item. Please review your question and provide additional details of your desired output.

Comment: Also avoid using reserved words as variable names. Although your name `List` is okay in that sense, using `list` as a variable name would shadow the class `list`. At least name it `my_list`, to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> ['VID' + item['VendorID'] + '&PID' + item['ProdID'] + ' ' + item['ProdStr'] for item in List]
```

For the `List` you provided above it will output:

```
['VID0xa34&PID0x4007 QWER1025', 'VID0xa34&PID0x4007 ASDF452x']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Building a list of strings and then using `''.join()` to concatenate them seems rather complicated. Why not use `+`?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Special thanks to @Szabolcs

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the dictionaries in the list.

```
for item in List:
    print "VID{}&PID{} {}".format(
        item["VendorID"], item["ProdID"], item["ProdStr"])
```

Answer (score 0):

What aboud string template and list comprehension?

```
infos = ( 'VID{}&PID{} {}'.format(item['VendorID'], item['ProdID'], item['ProdStr']) for item in List )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`print ['VID' + item['VendorID'] + '&PID' + item['ProdID'] + '  ' + item["ProdStr"] for item in List]`
```

Output: `['VID0xa34PID0x4007  QWER1025', 'VID0xa34PID0x4007  ASDF452x']`

Answer (score 0):

Try something​like this,

```
result = []
for item in List:
    all_string = "VID{}&PID{}{}".format(item['VendorID'], item['ProdID'], item['ProdStr'])
    result.append(all_string)
```